# C# Windows Forms - Weird multiline textbox behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, multiline, stringreader

I am using a `StringReader` to read input from a multi-line textbox. However, I am experiencing strange behaviour.
My Code:

```
string x = reader.ReadLine();
int y = int.Parse(x);
```

`x` is always an int.
My problem is that since `x` is the first line of the multiline textbox, it doesn't contain just the int, but `System.Windows.Forms.Textbox, Text:10`
Any help here?

I create the `StringReader` as following:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(Convert.ToString(multilinetbox)))
{

}
```

Comment: How do you create `StringReader`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your reader to read the `Text` property of the multiline textbox, instead of the entire control:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(multilinetbox.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are not asking this but still I thought to post it.

Why not try

```
foreach (string line in multilinetbox.Lines)
{
    int y = int.Parse(line);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Convert.ToString(multilinebox)` first converts the type information, and then get the text content.

You should change the multilinebox to multilinebox.Text.

Like

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(Convert.ToString(multilinetbox.Text)))
{    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have normal results for your code, because `Convert.ToString(multilinetbox)` converts it to text representation.

Try to user 'Lines' property instead:

```
foreach (string ln in textBox1.Lines)
{
    // some work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringReader rdr = new StringReader(textBox1.Text);
        int y = int.Parse(rdr.ReadLine());
    }
```

I think you made a mistake at your `StringReader` declaration.